# Bootstrap Select plugin - how to submit the form with it?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I'm trying to use Bootstrap Select plugin for a form I'm building. But the values selected don't get submitted into $_POST. Anybody has any experience with this Bootstrap plugin? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These links might be helpful for get the post values of select input:

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-select.html

http://www.formget.com/php-select-option-and-php-radio-button/

Generally bootstrap select input is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here **name** attribute is not specified in bootstrap select input, so you have to add **name** attribute to post the selected value of select list.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="Color">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: in the mean time I discovered the mistake myself. But you're right, I was missing the `name` attribute. Also, I should mention that I added the `[]` empty square brackets at the end of multi-select fields' name, to make it an array in $_POST. Great job buddy, thanks!