# Dropdown menu name in php

Tags: php, html

I have the following drop-down menu in a page:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Select a Category
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Cat I</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Cat II</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Cat III</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Cat IV</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Cat V</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

This is part of a form with POST method. How can I add the selected item to the `_POST` array? Should I specify a name somewhere in my code?

Comment: Use a <select> field instead of <ul> or you'll need to add a hidden field and some javascript to change the hidden field value

Comment: would i need to change the CSS that way? I'm currently using Bootstrap for this

Comment: Use drop down as <select></select>  or wirte some jquery code

Comment: it seems like you need bootstrap selectpicker as bootstrap uses. i am sure the same html created when we use bootsrap select picker with bootstrap library and its JS

Comment: In order to get form data you need to use form tags. If you need a custom layout for the select menu then use javascript to populate a hidden field

Comment: Take a look at this example select box with bootsrap [example](http://www.tutorialscollection.com/bootstrap-demo/bootstrap-demo.php?ex=4.1_2) also [Bootstrap Documentation](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#basic-examples)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Select plugin - how to submit the form with it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216187/bootstrap-select-plugin-how-to-submit-the-form-with-it)

Comment: @MarcoGreselin check out my solution below

Answer (score 0):

Use formcontrols: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls
example:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Category:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option>Cat 1</option>
    <option>Cat 2</option>
    <option>Cat 3</option>
    <option>Cat 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You can also overwrite the css for example:

```
form .form-group {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: ur code does not suite with the users requirements. User is using Bootstrap.

Comment: It does what I wanted. However, the look is not the one of the original. I assume it is only possible to get that look with JS...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method:

```
<form name="cat_form" id="cat_form" method="POST" />
    <input class="span2" id="cat_type" name="cat_type" type="hidden">
    <div>
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Select a Category<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li onclick="$('#cat_type').val('cat_1');">Cat 1</li>
        <li onclick="$('#cat_type').val('cat_2');">Cat 2</li>
        <li onclick="$('#cat_type').val('cat_3');">Cat 3</li>
        <li onclick="$('#cat_type').val('cat_3');">Cat 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where is the opening `<div>` tag? I understand whats going on but it doesn't work: once I click the dropdown does not appear.

Comment: @MarcoGreselin updated the answer. Please let me know if its working.